# how to change language for placeholder text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i cannot change language for my placeholder text. i can only change language for normal button text , head text but i cannot change language for placeholder text. please help to suggest anything i need to add on in my code. thanks

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Node.js app</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
            <div class="slider round">
                <span language='myanmar' class="on">MYN</span>
                <span language='english' class="off">ENG</span>
            </div>
        </label>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control usrplaceholder" placeholder="Username" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control pwplaceholder" name="pw" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        </div>
    
        <script>
    
            document.querySelector('#togBtn').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
                document.querySelector('.usrplaceholder').textContent = data[event.currentTarget.checked ? 'myanmar' : 'english'].usrplaceholder;
                document.querySelector('.pwplaceholder').textContent = data[event.currentTarget.checked ? 'myanmar' : 'english'].pwplaceholder;
            });
    
            var data = {
                "english": {
                    "usrplaceholder": "Username",
                    "pwplaceholder": "Password"
                },
                "japanese": {
                    "usrplaceholder": "အသုံးပြုသူအမည်",
                    "pwplaceholder": "စကားဝှက်",
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems in your code.

Firstly you're trying to access the `myanmar` property of the `data` object when it doesn't exist. The only properties, in the example code at least, as `english` and `japanese`.

Secondly, the `input` elements do not have a `textContent` property. From the context it looks like you're trying to set the `placeholder` property instead.

```js
document.querySelector('#togBtn').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  document.querySelector('.usrplaceholder').placeholder = data[event.currentTarget.checked ? 'japanese' : 'english'].usrplaceholder;
  document.querySelector('.pwplaceholder').placeholder = data[event.currentTarget.checked ? 'japanese' : 'english'].pwplaceholder;
});

var data = {
  "english": {
    "usrplaceholder": "Username",
    "pwplaceholder": "Password"
  },
  "japanese": {
    "usrplaceholder": "အသုံးပြုသူအမည်",
    "pwplaceholder": "စကားဝှက်",
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
  <div class="slider round">
    <span language='myanmar' class="on">MYN</span>
    <span language='english' class="off">ENG</span>
  </div>
</label>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control usrplaceholder" placeholder="Username" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control pwplaceholder" name="pw" placeholder="Password" required="required">
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh got it !! thank you Rory  :)